# Why does kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext.Element inherits from kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

We can provide an optional `CoroutineContext` while creating coroutine from builder functions like `launch` like this.

```
launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { // not confined -- will work with main thread
    println("Unconfined      : I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(500)
    println("Unconfined      : After delay in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}
```

One of the values is `Dispatchers.Unconfined`. I thought `Dispatchers.Unconfined` will inherit from `CoroutineContext` and it indeed does. But in a very convoluted way not very clear to me. Added the screen shot of the class hierarchy.

[image]

It inherits from the `CoroutineContext.Element` instead. Which is a nested interface inside the `CoroutineContext`. This nested interface inherits the outer/parent interface and all the useful implementations of `CoroutineContext` implement this nested interface.

I am not sure why this mechanics or where else such a pattern is used or can be used. The only place a nested interface AFAIK is used to created new namespaces like `Map.Entry`. The official documentation also says very little,

```
    /**
     * An element of the [CoroutineContext]. An element of the coroutine context is a singleton context by itself.
     */
```

Not really sure what `An element of the coroutine context is a singleton context by itself.` means.

I know this is a curiosity question. So timely response is not needed. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Only use case I know of `CoroutineContext.Element` is implementation of `plus` operator for easy stacking of contexts/scopes/exception handlers, ie. `launch(mainJob + childJob){ ... }` etc.

Answer (score 5):

A coroutine context is a set of elements. An element of the coroutine context is a singleton context by itself. It means that when viewed as a set (as a coroutine context) an element represents a single-element set (aka singleton).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really appreciate it. Never saw inner interface inheriting from its parent/outer interface. It was new for me. Still new.